# How to show realtime results of multiple python scripts in 1 window

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to run several python scripts simultaneously in the background, and have all the results be shown in 1 window, real time.  The background scripts will continue running, but as more info is outputted it should be shown inside 1 window.
I've tried os and subprocess, but to no avail.  This needs to work on all platforms.

Comment: In GNU/linux if you create a bash script and execute the scripts with the & at the end of the command, they should run independently and print on the same terminal. Don't know about other platforms, sorry

Comment: @Álvaro-Gómez I need them all to run at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, I haven't done much python, but could you not have your background scripts dump their results in a file and then have your window focus on updating when that file updates.

In linux you could write to a text file and then open another console window to tail that file.

Comment: Interesting idea, ill investigate and let you know how it goes!